# Scraping Python a

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2  tags with different contents inside the href tag and I just want one
I was wondering if it is possible for BeautifulSoup to be able to select only the href that starts with a particular word. If I Know Thank You.

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/" </a>
```

and the other

```
<a href="https://Instagram.com/" </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There many option to do it, here is 3 most common (CSS selector, regex and lambda):

```
data = '''
<a href="https://facebook.com/">TAG 1</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/">TAG 2</a>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

# 1st option - CSS selector
print(soup.select_one('a[href^="https://instagram"]'))

# 2nd option - using regexp
import re
print(soup.find('a', {'href': re.compile(r'^https://instagram')}))

# 3rd option - using lambda
print(soup.find(lambda tag: 'href' in tag.attrs and tag['href'].startswith('https://instagram')))
```

Prints:

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/">TAG 2</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/">TAG 2</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/">TAG 2</a>
```

---

EDIT: To select multiple links that starts with some string:

```
data = '''
<a href="https://facebook.com/">TAG 1</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/A">TAG 2</a>
<a href="https://facebook.com/">TAG 3</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/B">TAG 4</a>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('a[href^="https://instagram"]'):
    print(link)
```

Prints:

```
<a href="https://instagram.com/A">TAG 2</a>
<a href="https://instagram.com/B">TAG 4</a>
```

---

For CSS Selector reference use this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select(

Comment: how would I put the 1 option in that

Comment: and how would i filter only words inside the href = / video tag
or and only change within the Url parameter

Comment: @JacksuelSoaresBraga I don't quite understand. You can `soup.select('a[href*="/video"]')` that selects links that contain `/video` inside `href` attribute.

Comment: @JacksuelSoaresBraga To close the question you need to accept it (click on the checkmark next to the score)

Comment: And only from Doubt as I do for by type div before the command. ('a[href*="/view"]')

Comment: @JacksuelSoaresBraga Do you mean select `<a>` inside `<div>`? You can `soup.select('div a[href*="/video"]')` - here are CSS Selectors Reference https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: would you answer me?.

Comment: @JacksuelSoaresBraga I put link to CSS selectors reference to the answer.

Comment: (' a[href*="/view"]') to put the div in there would be (' div > a[href*="/view"]') ?

Comment: @JacksuelSoaresBraga Yes, this will select `<a>` tags directly under `<div>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example for you:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


html = """
<a href="https://facebook.com/"> </a>
<a href="https://Instagram.com/"> </a>
"""

page = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Iterate over 'a' elements and search if starts with "https://Insta"
for i in page.findAll("a"):
    if i.get("href").startswith("https://Insta"):
        instagram = i

# One line and regex version:
facebook = [i for i in page.findAll("a") if re.match("^https://face", i.get("href"))][0]

print(facebook)
print(instagram)
```

**Output:**

```py
<a href="https://facebook.com/"> </a>
<a href="https://Instagram.com/"> </a>
```